# Disabling the select tag field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, sharepoint

I'm having trouble figuring out how to disable a select tag but keeping the selected value visible. The only solution I've found was to remove the items that should not be displayed. The use is that when a user created a new item and selects an option, the people viewing the created item should not be able to change it. Greying out text boxes has proved to be pretty simple but I don't know how to proceed with select tags.

This is how I do it right now but not exactly since this code follows a progression and gives editors different options depending on the stage they're in. However, other choice fields won't change through the process, they just need to remain what they were on creation.

```
//On item edit, set status to In Progress if in New
    if($("option[value='New']").attr("selected") == "selected"){
        //Disable New/Completed/Cancelled
        $("option[value='New']").remove();
        $("option[value='Completed']").remove();
        $("option[value='Cancelled']").remove();                

        //Enable In Progress
        $("option[value='In Progress']").attr("selected","selected");

        //Call Claim WO Function
        claimOrder();

    }else if($("option[value='In Progress']").attr("selected") == "selected"){
        //Remove New option
        $("option[value='New']").remove();
        $("option[value='In Progress']").remove();
        $("option[value='Completed']").attr("selected","selected");
    }else if($("option[value='Completed']").attr("selected") == "selected"){
        //Remove New/In Progress option when Completed/Cancelled
        $("option[value='New']").remove();
        $("option[value='In Progress']").remove();
        $("option[value='Cancelled']").remove();    
    }else if($("option[value='Cancelled']").is(':selected')){
        //Remove New/In Progress option when Completed/Cancelled
        $("option[value='New']").remove();
        $("option[value='In Progress']").remove();
        $("option[value='Completed']").remove();
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about disabling like this

```
box.attr('disabled', 'disabled')
```